# What Ray Bradbury story contains a line about autumn burning the land?

Tags: story-identification, ray-bradbury

What Ray Bradbury story contains the line...

> ..."Autumn was burning the land down into winter.  The smoke of the burning, thick, blue, and invisible...."

Since I cannot google it up, I suspect I may remember it incorrectly, but I would bet that it is close to this.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[Google got me here](http://albertwendland.blogspot.com/2013/10/descriptions-of-autumn-ray-bradbury-and.html).  It seems to be from "Pillar of Fire", and this is the full quote:

> The smells of the world were all about him.  Frustratedly, he tried to smell the smells of autumn.   Autumn was burning the land down into ruin.  All across the country the ruins of summer lay; vast forests bloomed with flame, tumbled down timber on empty, unleafed timber.  The smoke of the burning was rich, blue, and invisible.

[Here's the near-nonexistent Wikipedia page on it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pillar_of_Fire_and_Other_Plays), or possibly what was based on it.  The entire contents at this time are:

> ***Pillar of Fire and Other Plays*** (1975) is a collection of three plays by Ray Bradbury: Pillar of Fire, Kaleidoscope, and The Foghorn. All are adaptations of his short stories of the same names.

Based on the dates, the reference in the initial article seems to indicate the quote is from the original short story:

> Bradbury, Ray.  “Pillar of Fire.”  1948.  Anthony Boucher, ed.  *A Treasury of Great Science Fiction.*  Vol. 1.  New York:  Doubleday, 1959.  141-169.