# Short story of an animated dead man in a world with no fear of death

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this short story in an anthology, most likely in the 80s, possibly in the 90s.

The setting is a future in which the living no longer fear death.  One consequence of that is that they are disinterring cemeteries to recover the land and (possibly) cremating the remains.

The protagonist is a dead man who has been disturbed by being disinterred and, somehow animated, is wandering.  He has an interaction with a little girl in which he learns that people no longer fear death; he may have killed the little girl.

The protagonist is "caught" when someone offers him a ride, and a cigarette, and the lack of breathing became obvious due to the cigarette.

Comment: I don't think he kils a little girl, but he engineers the explosion of a power plant, and sneaks into the temporary morgue to try to convince the dead to rise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Pillar of Fire](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58422) by Ray Bradbury

> And then I gave you a cigarette and you sucked and blew, sucked and
> blew. None of it ever came out your nose...Something is not in the room when a man is dead in it.

Also the answer to this old question: [What Ray Bradbury story contains a line about autumn burning the land?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/63808)

Comment: The synopsis on ISFDb is quite good: "A man who died in 1933 finds himself awakening in 2349 as his grave is being excavated, as all dead people are now being cremated as part of an effort to eliminate any dark or disturbing influences, including the work of Bierce, Poe, Lovecraft, etc.; the rage this generates within him at the loss of an important part of human heritage is the force which animates him as he resolves to create an army of others like him and reverse the trend."